# Event Mechanism in SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, change-data-capture

I have a windows service that constantly queries a table in DB1 and if any changes are found in it, it transfers those changes to DB2. For that, it constantly queries the DB1.

Is there any mechanism by which I can subscribe to an event in DB1 such that any changes in table is notified to the window service ?

The tables in DB1 are capture tables which have only the changed values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is such a mechanism, named [Notification services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms166495%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx), **but** it only valid for sql 2005, in 2008 you can use the well known other options:

- SSIS
- replication
- Log shipping
- mirroring
- custom triggers and modifications queue tables

which need not the intermediate services to run with, except the last one

Comment: Notification Service is not supported in 2008.

Comment: Yep, sorry, so you can use another options. I'll correct the answer

Comment: Your answer makes it sound like the alternative options only work on 2008, whereas in fact most of them date back to at least 2005 or 2000 (e.g. replication).